# Dynamic Validation in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to validate a particular request depending on values in a database. It's a complex scenario, but I will try to simplify it in an example.

Say I have the following model:

```
public class CustomerModel 
{
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

When a POST request comes in, I need to make a call to get certain requirements for the AgencyId being passed.

```
var requirements = _repository.GetRequirementsForAgency(model.AgencyId);
```

The information I would get back from the database would tell me which properties are required, which may be different for each agency. For instance, one agency might require Name and Age where as another one might only require Name. The requirements object would look something like this:

```
public class Requirement
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

So, my question is what would be the best way to validate this model before it gets submitted to the database? Ideally, I would like to give the Agency the ability to change these requirements, therefore, I would like to avoid hard coding validation if possible.

My first thought was to call a list of requirements and then do a foreach over each requirement searching by PropertyName and then checking to see if there was a value or not, but I wasn't sure if this was the best way.

I then looked into Data Annotations, but did not find a way to add attributes at run time.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Fluent Validation library](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) and implement custom validator

```
public class CustomerModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerModel>
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public RegisterModelValidator(IRepository repository)
    {
        this._repository= repository;

        RuleFor(x => x.AgencyId).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Invalid AgencyId");
        RuleFor(x => x.Age).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Invalid Age");
        Custom(c =>
                {
                    var requirements = _repository.GetRequirementsForAgency(model.AgencyId);
                    \\validate each property according to requirements object.
                    \\if (Validation fails for some property)
                        return new ValidationFailure("property", "message");
                    \\else
                    return null;
                });
    }
}
```

If you use dependency injection in your project (which i strongly advice), you will have to inject relevant IRepository into an attribute. Otherwise you can just create/use a specific repository in your attribute.

A really nice thing is when you [properly register your validator](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) you will be able to validate you model with default `if (ModelState.IsValid)` check